# Ionic: silently login an "admin" account to Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I'm running an Ionic app on localhost. I need to login an "admin" account to manage some data. I get the attached error when I run following code:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "****",
      authDomain: "****.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://****.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "****.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "****"
});

this.db = firebase.database();
this.db.ref('/settings').once('value').then((snap)=>console.log(snap.val()))
```

I think the problem is that I'm not authenticated (I temporarily changed the firebase rules to read/write = true and the error disappeared). How can I authenticate? Maybe, I have to use a different approach? (I tried a lot using angularfire, without success)

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for 1) logout then 2) login anonymously

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth